# python 2.7 + winpexpect 1.6 not working on win10?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have installed python 2.7 along with winpexpect 1.6 (the fork from here: https://bitbucket.org/weyou/winpexpect/wiki/Home). On Win7 everything worked smooth and perfectly. Now I upgraded to Win10 and suddenly the winspawn command hangs up. For example the following command:

import winpexpect
child = winpexpect.winspawn('c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe')

just never comes back. No error message, no exception, no reaction at all.

Does anybody have an idea, what might have happened or what I could do to further investigate the problem?

Add: I run Win10 64 bit, use python 2.7 (Anaconda) 32 bit. When I run a frozen binary (built on the previous Win7 system) along with a stub - everything still works fine. But I can't rebuild it anymore.

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report. It's quite expected that something in Win10 can break backward compatibility when it first comes out. Let the experts figure it out. It takes time for this kind of migration. For now, maybe you can submit your tests to other towers, assuming you have access to some?

Comment: Honestly, I am a simple "user", I have no idea how to contact anybody - or who? I did some researches and the problem seems to be inside the "_spawn"-method, line 560 of winpexpect.py:

`ConnectNamedPipe(cmd_pipe)`

This is the command that will never come back.

Comment: Hi,  you may want to start here [link](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/issues?status=new&status=open)